# The Download for SWTOR stopped at 99.95%?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, I've reached the end of my "quests" and stuff on the planet, but because the game isn't "fully downloaded" it's not letting me leave. It's been stuck at 99.95% for downloading for about two or three weeks now, and it's kind of pissing me off because I would like to move on in my gameplay.

How can I make the game download the rest of the update?

Comment: How did you download it? Are you using any programs like uTorrent or Vuse?

Comment: Shut down SWTOR if it is running. First thing to do is to go to the place where you installed SWTOR. Rightclick the shortcut in your startmenu or on the desktop and choose "Open File Location". In the Folder SWTOR there should be a file called "Diskcachearena". Delete this one, then launch it again and see if it completes. It is safe to delete it, because it is recreated when you launch the game

Comment: If the above does not work, there is a FixLauncher.exe in the SWTOR Folder. Run that one and report the results.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Even if it's not *the* solution, it's still *a* solution. I would suggest posting it as an answer.

Comment: So there is no error message, it's just hanging at 99.95%?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have been having errors related to the downloads since the lastest expansion. I kept getting "unable to retrieve patch data (311)", and several guildies have had the same problem you did.

Apparently some people have been having problems with their hosts. Instructions for changing this have been posted on the SWTOR forums:

http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=759127

But basically, the instructions are:

Press Windows Key+R to open a Run Line.

> To access the hosts file in Windows 7 you can use the following
>   command in the Run Line to open notepad and the file.
>
> notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
>
> and
>
> add
>
> 209.84.0.254 cdn-patch.swtor.com

Alternately

1. Right click Notepad
2. Run it as Administrator
3. Click File, then Open
4. Type "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" and press Open
5. Add "209.84.0.254 cdn-patch.swtor.com" on a new line
6. Save the file.

More information about hosts files, and how to change it in other Windows versions:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/

This fix worked for me, and several of my SWTOR guildmates.

Comment: First off, you need to run cmd.exe as administrator to edit this file, second I doubt she knows how to run the Command Shell. Also, this should never be necessary. A `ipconfig /flushdns` should be the first thing to do in case the IP for the cdn server changed.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to run cmd for it at all (in windows 7). Just copy and paste the "notepad c:/windows" etc into the run line, and it will open the file in notepad. I will add how to get a run line up though.

Comment: Yes, just run notepad as admin and open `%windir%\system32\etc\hosts`. Can paste this into the open file dialog.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell I did all that the above instructions provided by you two told me to do, and started up SWTOR, and it doesn't seem to have done anything

Comment: @LydiaG. Did you do what I told you?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Yeah, I did that also, it's still stuck at 99.95%

Comment: @LydiaG. Ok, another method is to delete the folder called "BitRaider" in the installation directory while SWTOR is closed. Then run the launcher again. If this does not help, you might just want to uninstall the game and reinstall it, even though it sucks due to the size. Make sure to redownload the installer in that case.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness That definitely worked. Thank you a lot